# Center both image and text inline on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a full-width label, with dynamic text so it can be two characters or ten. I need to display an image inline on the left part, always 10px away from the first letter. Please see the example below.

[image: Short text example]

[image: Large text example]

For now, I just put a full-width label and at runtime, I measure the text width with `boundingRectWithSize:` method, and adjust my image constraints programmatically.

**Do you have any good idea to build this kind of interface without measuring manually the text width?**

Comment: Have a look at `+ (NSAttributedString * nonnull)attributedStringWithAttachment:(NSTextAttachment * nonnull)attachment`

Comment: objective-c or swift?

Comment: Why don't use auto-layout?

Comment: @Lorenzo could you be more specific? any implementation idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Objective - C*

You can add image as text attachment.

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
UIImage *imageTest=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
attachment.image = imageTest;
NSMutableAttributedString *myString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My label text "];
NSMutableAttributedString *myStringWithArrow = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment]];
[myStringWithArrow appendAttributedString:myString];
yourLabel.attributedText = myStringWithArrow;
```

*Swift*

```
var attachment = NSTextAttachment()
var imageTest = UIImage(named:"arrow.png")
attachment.image = imageTest
var myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "My label text ")
var myStringWithArrow = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
myStringWithArrow.appendAttributedString(myString)
lblAttributed.attributedText = myStringWithArrow
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Wow that's just perfect, that's what I'm looking for! Actually my app is in Swift but I don't care, I got the concept. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @hagile Thanks! I will try in swift.

Comment: @AshishKakkad I just added the Swift version, don't worry. Thanks!

Comment: @hagile I submitted it, it should be in peer review :)

Comment: @sweepy_ I have updated answer with swift code. I think peer review will cancelled because of my update.

Comment: @sweepy_ sorry. I seen your code in the review. That's good effort. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

@ashish-kakkad's answer is perfect but unless you need a pixel-perfect image you can use a Unicode symbol:

[image]

```
[self.button1 setTitle:@"\u27A4 Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Most of the Unicode symbols with codes could be found here http://unicode-table.com/

Comment: Thanks, actually I really need to include a `IImage` instance but that's a good point though.

Comment: Woo, never think of this !! Amazing.